# The stylesheet broken when loading different layout in different controllers

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

Hi I got a strange problem.

When I clicked three pages shown in the following three images

**Step 1**
controller welcome

**Step 2**
other controllers

**Step 3, go back to the step1 view**
controller welcome

The last image, 
when I back to `controller welcome` from the `other controllers`
,that is step 2 to step 3.

The stylesheets were cached by the browser,

The **step 3's** layout is differ to **step1** layout.

But they are the same page,How could it be, it seems the browser caches the css files ?

I add two assets folder used by the two layouts, in  `application.rb`
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/themes"

```
    themes
├── ace-admin-theme
│   ├── avatars
│   ├── css
│   ├── font
│   ├── images
│   ├── img
│   └── js
└── lenord-single-page-theme
    ├── css
    ├── fonts
    ├── img
    ├── index.html
    ├── js
    └── rs-assets
```

Added the `welcome.html.haml` under layouts folder, so that `welcome_controller` can load this layout

```
layouts
├── _header.html.haml
├── application.html.haml
└── welcome.html.haml
```

All the source code I put here https://gist.github.com/poc7667/0198b973fce0fbf4dd26

**Page A : OK**
[image]
**Page B : OK**
[image]
**Page A : Failed, the Page B's stylesheets are cached, it should be identical to original page A**
[image]

It didn't work when I comment the `data-turbolinks-track` for the css

The strange phenomenon still occurs.

```
--- a/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
+++ b/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 %html
   %head
     %title VIVOTEK DQA DEVELOPER
-    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
+    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
     = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
     / Description, Keywords and Author
     / basic styles
diff --git a/app/views/layouts/welcome.html.haml b/app/views/layouts/welcome.html.haml
index 28d9c99..c3e6ec8 100644
--- a/app/views/layouts/welcome.html.haml
+++ b/app/views/layouts/welcome.html.haml
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 %html
   %head
     %title VIVOTEK DQA DEVELOPER
-    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
+    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
     = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

I open the firebug to see the included css files,
I found I need to reload the page to load the expected css files.
How to fix it ?

[image]

---

### Update

When I reload page, the console showed those css files were loaded

```
Started GET "/assets/ace-admin-theme/css/bootstrap.min.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-19 14:33:49 +0800
Started GET "/assets/ace-admin-theme/css/font-awesome.min.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-19 14:33:49 +0800
```

When I click a hyperlink(by url helper) to other pages the css won't be load again.

But actually it should load the css files again, because some controllers use the different layout and assets.

But what's the worse is that if I click the link (generated by URLhelper) the problems happens
`But if I go to the page by typing the URL on the browser manually, it works fine!!`

To brief, the css files only load in the first time, and other necessary css files(for other layout) won't be load anymore.(If I view the page by clicking the URLHelperLink), but it works by manually type the URL on the browser (for example: localhost:3000/welcome, localhost:3000/urlcommands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
How could it be, it seems the browser caches the css files ?
```

**Turbolinks**

That might appear to be the case if you're using [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) - which loads a new version of the `<body>` tag (leaving `<head>`). This would make your browser use the same CSS each request (where `turbolinks` is firing) problem would only be present if you're using the same `layout`

This may not be the problem (if you're changing layouts, the entire page will refresh)

A way to test this is to turn off turbolinks:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

If you do this, Rails should refresh your whole page every time. This will allow you to see whether the styling will change each time

---

**CSS**

The other issue you may have is how you're calling your CSS. If you've got a different layout for step 3 - are you calling different CSS?

Personally, I would just use different styling for the different steps & incorporate them into the same spreadsheet.

Here's how I'd do it with SASS:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
.service
    .step1 
       //styling

    .step2
       //styling

    .step3
       //styling
```

---

**Update**

I would say the issue here is likely to be your structure of your code with Turbolinks. I'm 90% sure the issue will be with Turbolinks (especially as you wrote you "need to refresh" the doc to make the CSS work)

Can you share your layouts & how you're calling them in your controllers?

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution , but it didn't work. I updated my post, thanks for your help

Comment: I open the firebug to see the included css files,
I found I need to reload the page to load the expected css files.
How to fix it ?

Comment: It's going to be a turbolinks issue - let me finish some writing & come back. I'll be about 20 minutes

Comment: Hi I've already put my code here https://gist.github.com/poc7667/0198b973fce0fbf4dd26

Comment: When I reload page, the console showed those css files were loaded
    

    Started GET "/assets/ace-admin-theme/css/bootstrap.min.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-19 14:33:49 +0800
    Started GET "/assets/ace-admin-theme/css/font-awesome.min.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-19 14:33:49 +0800

When I click a hyperlink to other pages the css won't be load again.
But actually it should load the css files again, because some controllers use the different layout and assets.

Comment: Can you confirm the other layouts are loading as required?

Comment: To brief, the css files only load in the first time, and other necessary css files(for other layout) won't be load anymore.(If I view the page by clicking the URLHelperLink), but it works by manually type the URL on the browser (for example: localhost:3000/welcome, localhost:3000/urlcommands)

Comment: And you've disabled turbolinks as I recommended?

Comment: Sorry for giving you troubles, it fixed by comment out the `turbolink`

Comment: is there any way, to let the `turbolink` still works in my case?

Comment: Sure! Turbolinks just needs some tweaking. Your problem will be with how you're calling your layouts. Can you give me a link to your github repo for the app? I'll look at your layouts for you in there

Comment: `https://gist.github.com/poc7667/0198b973fce0fbf4dd26` the welcome.html.haml is put under layout folder , so only affect on the welcome controller

Comment: Thanks for the update! So how are you assigning the `welcome` layout to the requested action? Can you post that code too?