# Rails turbolinks breaks css on loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Hopefully title is not misleading. My problem is - when using turbolinks and clicking on a link, the page, which gets loaded, seems to have no styling for a split second. Then, css loads and everything works fine. But this behavior is very user unfriendly.

I can fix that by removing turbolinks, which works. But I rely on `turbolinks.visit` in some other parts of my code.

I can also fix this by adding `method: :get` to every `=link_to` helper.

Both methods are kind of 'hacky'. Is there a way to fix it the 'right way'?

You can experience what I mean by clicking here on the logo (top left) -http://uzhindoma.eve-trader.net (no modifications) and then on one of the three nav links (there is `method: :get`).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625635/the-stylesheet-broken-when-loading-different-layout-in-different-controllers?rq=1) similar SO question, but there is no solution provided.

This is my application layout:

```
!!!

%html
%head
  %title Uzhindoma - Front
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'front', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = stylesheet_link_tag "https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.20.0/mapbox-gl.css", :rel => "stylesheet"
  = stylesheet_link_tag "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700", :rel => "stylesheet"
  = csrf_meta_tags

%body{class: "#{controller_name} #{action_name} g-body"}
  .g-content
    =render 'front/navigation/header'
    / Rendering errors
    %section
      -flash.each do |name, msg|
        =content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}")
    =yield
    =render 'front/navigation/footer'


= javascript_include_tag "https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.28.0/mapbox-gl.js"
= javascript_include_tag 'front', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
= javascript_include_tag "https://widget.cloudpayments.ru/bundles/cloudpayments"
```

And here is my front.js

```
// Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
// All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
// You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/front/custom/.


//= require_self
//= require_tree ../../../app/assets/javascripts/front/.
//= require turbolinks
```

If I remove `//= require turbolink`, then linking works just fine, but I won't get some redirects (which rely on `TurboLinks.visit` method)

To decide, which layout to use with which controller, I've got following controller structure:
`controllers/application_controller.rb`
`controllers/front_controller.rb`
`controllers/admin_controller.rb`
`controllers/front/...`
`controllers/admin/...`

application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "front"
    end
  end
end
```

front_controller:

```
class FrontController < ApplicationController
    layout 'front'
end
```

admin_controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
    layout "admin"
end
```

Comment: Great website, I that is a real lag in css. Would be nice if you add some code snippets where you think the problem is. Are you using different CSS stylesheet ? How are you including them.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! I added my application layout. I'm using two of them - `front` for the public part and `admin` for the admin part. They are using different sets of css and js.

Comment: How do you decide which CSS and Javascript to use ? Maybe you are calling code twice.

Comment: I'm deciding it in the controllers (updated question)